# Memory allocation in embedded systems

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, embedded, malloc

Linux/Unix systems often run on x86 CPU architecture which provides a MMU for memory mapping, but I guess embedded systems lack this, so no `malloc` and `free`.

I saw that ES programmers can create a big static buffer to reserve memory:

```
unsigned char mem[10240];
```

But I wonder how it works, where does the buffer start exactly, and how the C compiler can map variable definitions to actual memory locations on some platforms.

I have also seen such constants in ES headers (extracted from the ARM `STM32L1xx`):

```
#define SRAM_BASE ((uint32_t)0x20000000) /*!< SRAM base address in the alias region */
```

I understand that SRAM stands for "Static" RAM but does "base address" means the beginning of the memory area reserved to heap/stack access, so a programmer could allocate and free chunks of RAM using a pointer to this base address and a linked list of blocks ?

Comment: Malloc and free do not require an MMU.

Comment: I saw some "homemade" implementations of malloc using various techniques, but the malloc I use in my system uses the mmap system call, which uses the MMU.

Comment: Also, ES implementations of malloc are hardware-dependent: it must use these base addresses constants for DMA since you don't have a MMU.

Comment: Your question is much too broad.  It depends on the hardware, toolchain and libraries used. Some may implement malloc "family" functions another not

Comment: `unsigned char *mem[10240];` is not probably typed as you'd want... Perhaps you meant `unsigned char mem[10240];`

Comment: The ES malloc implementations are rather homemade micro libraries usually made from a base address to the physical memory and a linked list of memory chunks.

Comment: @Prion they are never done this way on the resource limited systems.

Comment: @Prion what has DMA in common with heap management functions? Do you know what the DMA is?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but those "base addresses" constants refer to physical memory, so accessing them means direct memory access, no ?

Comment: No. Accessing physical memory is not what is described by "Direct memory access". DMA is, simplified, accessing memory without using the CPU, e..g a peripheral storing larger chunks of data slowly and then only notifying CPU when done.

Comment: How is this possible, motherboard chipset ?

Comment: Please turn that into a separate question "What is DMA and how does it work?".

Comment: I will when this question will be "solved".

Comment: I consider it answered. Adding more questions in comments does not make it unanswered.

Comment: If you want more info on parts of your original question, then please answer the questions you were asked in comments, e.g. concerning your knowledge about linker configuration, as asked by @P__J__

Comment: Since "big static array buffers" and "base addresses" to the beginning of a memory area are the same things (in terms of memory access and reservation), why would someone use the former over the latter ?

Comment: In order to make sure that the memory after the base address is free, i.e. not used by anything else, especially not the linker. Do you know about the linker? Do you know about configuring it? Especially to be aware of but not use the area after the base address? Really, in your own interest, if you are asked questions in comments, please answer them. Please.

Comment: malloc and free are not required in a freestanding environment. And a lot of embedded systems don't use them due to several reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedded System is a very broad term. It may mean the micro controller without the operating system or "normal" computer with the OS.

Some examples:

- uC reading the sensors and controlling the water flow through the pipe.
- Raspberry Pi run under Linux controlling the drone (it is embedded into the drone)
- PC computer controlling the laser cutter .
- mainframe computer in a radio telescope system

So there is no one answer to your question.

uCs will be programmed completely different way than the RPi used in the drone.

But your question is probably about the uC systems I think.

uC systems are usually programming is sometimes called a "bare metal" because programmers do not have the immediate software (abstraction layer) between their application and the actual hardware. So they access the memory, hardware registers and another resources directly. Even operating systems used in the bare metal development (called RTOS-es) are not even similar to the normal OSes like Linux or Windows. They are more libraries linked together with the bare metal application and just provide mechanisms of task management and communication, synchronization and data exchange.

Some questions you asked in the comments

DMA - Direct memory access - allows data transfer between the memory and peripherals or memory with no use of the processor core. Some uC have very complicated DMA & event systems - for example the timer overflow can trigger the ADC which triggers the DMA transfer storing the converted data into the memory.

Linker Script - defines what, how and where is stored in the memory. They may me very complicated and instruct that code or data to include or exclude, and how to organize the program memory. Below you have an example of the linker script for the STM32 family uC

```
/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

_estack = 0x10004000;    /* end of RAM */

/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x100;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x1000; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 64K
CCMRAM (rw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 16K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000 + 32K, LENGTH = 512K - 34K
}

_FLASH_SIZE = LENGTH(FLASH);

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _vectors_start = .;
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _vectors_end = .;
  } >FLASH

  .sizedata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.sizedata))
    KEEP(*(.sizedata*)) 
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH  

    .flashdata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.rodata))         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    KEEP(*(.rodata*))       /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH




  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH


  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);
   _ROMEND = .;


  /* Initialized data sections goes into CCMRAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)           /* .data sections */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >CCMRAM AT> FLASH

   _ROMSIZE = _ROMEND - ORIGIN(FLASH) + _edata - _sdata;

  _siccmram = ORIGIN(CCMRAM);
    _sconfig = _ROMSIZE;
  _econfig = _sconfig + 2K;
    .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >CCMRAM

  /* RAM section 
  */

      /* Uninitialized data section */
   .dummy :
   {
   . = ALIGN(4);
   *(.dummy)
   *(.dummy*)
   . = ALIGN(4);
   } > RAM AT > FLASH

  .ram :
  {  
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sram = .;       /* create a global symbol at ccmram start */
    *(.ram)
    *(.ram*)   
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _eram = .;       /* create a global symbol at ccmram end */
  } >RAM 

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack (NOLOAD):
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >CCMRAM



  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }


  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

MMU - some uCs have memory management units - but usually this peripheral only protects some memory areas. As you do not have the OS, you also do not have the file system - so nothing like mmap exists.

```
  #define SRAM_BASE ((uint32_t)0x20000000)
```

it only defines in the human readable form the address of something. In this case probably it is just the address of the beginning of the SRAM memory. Another example:

```
#define PERIPH_BASE           ((uint32_t)0x40000000U)
#define APB2PERIPH_BASE       (PERIPH_BASE + 0x00010000U)
#define SPI1_BASE             (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x00003000U)
#define SPI1                ((SPI_TypeDef *) SPI1_BASE)
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. I was referring to uC and yes it makes it clearer.

Comment: Also, mmap does not necessarily uses the filesystem, MAP_ANONYMOUS with a file descriptor of -1 is used to extent the heap region in linux/unix systems.

Comment: @Prion as always - very imprecise. In Linux everything is file system related. In this case /dev/zero.

Comment: BSD systems do not have this flag and you need to archive the same another way:     `fd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDWR);   
    a = mmap(NULL, length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);`  It is not used to extend the heap only to avoid virtuall address space fragmentation, allocate outside the global heap and immediately return the memory to the system after unmapping

Comment: MMU - Memory Management Unit, MPU - Memory Protection Unit ... some µCs might have just an MPU, or not even this.

Comment: @kesselhaus and what has it in common with my answer?

Comment: @P__J__ Don't be offended, I'm with you here. I just wanted to say, the part doing the memory access protection is called commonly MPU. And, that MCUs can have none of it, just a MPU, multi-core MCUs maybe for all cores (or just some) and maybe a system-MPU for bus accesses to memories, and some might have full MMUs.

Answer (score 3):

I get the impression that there are some misunderstandings related to this question. Let me try to sort them out.

The function malloc and free do not require an MMU.
The fact that you have seen one implementation using the MMU does not mean it is always needed.
While an MMU might make implementing easier and in case of a PMMU even postpone the failure of attempted mallocs (by using virtual memory), implementing those two functions on statically allocated variables is possible. Using appropriatly large arrays (as you mention) is a way to do so. I did so in at least two different cases, to accommodate immplementations of applications which use dynamic memory allocation.
Note that on embedded systems extended knowledge about the system behaviour is needed, in order to use appropriate algorithms and size to avoid running out of memory (usually caused or exarcerbated by fragementation). But for embedded system that knowledge is sometimes available.

Using such an array means that it is first allocated perfectly normally by the linker, like any other (large) variable.
The address is therefor determined by the linker, according to configuration and system attributes. One likely location is inside the BSS segment (global or static variables without specific value initialisation).

The last paragraph of your question is especially unclear and seems to switch between multiple topics.
Yes, SRAM is for static RAM. The "static" in that is however not related to any of the meanings according to C syntax. The "static" of SRAM refers to the hardware implementation of the memory. It is in contrast to dynamic RAM. Dynamic RAM is much cheaper than static RAM, it does however require regular refreshing. The refreshing is practically always handled by an MMU but I do not see any relation to the other case of MMU-need you mentioned. SRAM can keep its content just with power supply, DRAM loses content after quite short a time. SRAM therefor can be used in embedded systems to keep content across phases in which the CPU is practically dead, often referred to as "low power modes".

The term "base address" has many meanings. It can refer to e.g. the lowest address of an area used to allocate BSS variables, or the lowest address of an area used for dynamic memory management.

A progorammer allocates memory dynamically NOT by giving a pointer, it is done by asking for a pointer instead, which is the return value of e.g. a successful malloc attempt.

The implementation allocates dynamic memory inside a memory area available for specifically that purpose (which might be the mentioned large array). If memory is available (e.g. there are still blocks found in a linked list of free blocks), it returns an address inside one of them (which is of course followed by enough free space to accomodate the requested size) and keeps information on the remaining (if any) free memory (e.g. by inserting that now smaller space back into the linked list). If not enough memory is left anymore, the return value indicates failure.

Comment: Dynamic allocation on the resource limited hardware may lead to very quick memory fragmentation and I personally try to avoid it. Programming resource limited targets is different than programing "normal" computers.

Comment: @P__J__ I agree and I mention thast in my question. You seem to just agree with me. Would you like to elaborate an issue you have with my question? I would be happy to improve with your input.

Comment: comment does not always mean problem :)

Comment: How is the linker responsible for the memory allocation of a static buffer ? And for the "base address" I was referring to the programmer asking (or creating) a pointer to this base address. I mean, using a big static buffer or a pointer to a base address is the same thing no ? In both cases you refer to a contiguous memory area (considering the base address refers to physical memory).

Comment: @P__J__ What a relief. On this non-trivial topic I will take a neutral comment as a compliment.

Comment: The linker is responsible for the location of ALL static variables.

Comment: Using a pointer to the base address of any kind of memory is only similar to allocating it correctly if you happen to know that this memory is NOT used by anything else. If it IS used you have to ask either linker for permission (by defining a large variable in there) or the memory manager by using e.g. malloc().

Comment: @Prion have you ever heard about linker scripts?

Comment: I asked this question out of a school project that requires you to "recode" malloc on unix systems. It's basically a mmap wrapper and not very interesting. But for ES, I was just wondering how their malloc was implemented, browsing some snippets, I stumbled upon those big static arrays and on some "base addresses" constants. I was trying to figure out what those "base addresses" were exactly, and why some headers define such constants, and some others declare big static arrays.

Comment: PJS questions about linker scripts is relevant. Please answer it.

Comment: When you use a static array you need to provide the linker about the memory area your program will use to allocate the array buffer. You don't have this problem using base addresses constants. What exactly are linker scripts in ES ?

Comment: @P__J__ I don't know what linker scripts are. I have the basic academic knowledge of what a linker is, resolving the symbols of multiple translation units and making references.

Comment: A "linker script" (other names exist for that) allows e.g. to make the linker aware of a given memory area, but also instruct the linker not to use any of it. The result is a less convenient way to reserve a memory area of a certain size. Only in case that OTHER reasons exist for making sure that the area is at a specific location, using a linker script is helpful.

Comment: If you want more details on linker configuration either make a separate question or read your linkers documentation and follow some tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I think the base addresses constants are a better way to reference memory on ES, it makes it clearer to people reading code. And it doesn't require linker scripts for memory configuration.

Comment: I disagree. You will have to prevent your linker from putting other variables into any location which obviously is suitable for that. You need to learn about linker configuration for that. If you do not need to keep your linker from using perfectly usable memory then you need to learn about linker configuration to fix that major restriction of resources on your system.

Comment: @Prion you are completely wrong. You try to understand advanced topis without having the basic knowledge. You need to learn a bit more before starting the discussions.